# How do I open new links outside of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, hyperlink

Is there any way to make an iframe act as if it were part of the page. Such as when I click a link, it either will open the links in a new tab/window by default, or have it so that when a link is clicked, it will open in the same window, but not just the iframe?

Comment: Is this iframe on your domain?  If not, I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: Yes, the iframe is on my domain, but the content inside the iframe is not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just set the [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/a) attribute.  To open in the current top window (top frame):

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_top">Link Text</a>
```

Or to open in a new window:

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">Link Text</a>
```

There's also `_parent` for the parent window (not necessarily the top) and `_self` for the current window (the default).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have control of the content that is in the `iframe`?

You could use `target=_top` for the links.

Comment: No, I do not have control of the content in the iframe. That is where I am stuck.